# TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

After cloning a repo, `npm install` && `ionic cordova build android --prod` shows me following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at checkUnreachable (F:\Works\Projects\ionic-bokfinder\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24905:31)
    at bindChildrenWorker (F:\Works\Projects\ionic-bokfinder\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23111:17)
    at bindChildren (F:\Works\Projects\ionic-bokfinder\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23055:17)
    at bind (F:\Works\Projects\ionic-bokfinder\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24319:21)
    at bindSourceFile
```

I am sure it worked well without any problems before. Here are my system information and package.json.

> System:
>
> ```
>     Node : v8.10.0
>     npm  : 5.6.0
>     OS   : Windows 10
> ```
>
> Package.json:
>
> ```
> "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
>     "@ionic-native/core": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/intercom": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.5.2",
>     "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
>     "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
>     "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
>     "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
>     "firebase": "^4.12.0",
>     "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
>     "ionicons": "3.0.0",
>     "raven-js": "^3.17.0",
>     "rxjs": "5.5.2",
>     "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
>     "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
>     "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.8",
>     "@types/jasmine": "2.8.4",
>     "@types/node": "9.3.0",
>     "html-loader": "0.5.5",
>     "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.0",
>     "jasmine": "2.9.0",
>     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
>     "karma": "2.0.0",
>     "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
>     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.3",
>     "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
>     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
>     "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
>     "karma-webpack": "2.0.9",
>     "protractor": "5.2.2",
>     "ts-loader": "3.2.0",
>     "ts-node": "4.1.0",
>     "tslint": "5.9.1",
>     "typescript": "2.4.2"
>   },
> ```

I guess this problem is related with `@ionic/app-scripts` [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1347).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing `@angular/cli` should work for you

if not, change Typescript version to `~2.6.2`.

`@angular/cli` `1.7.3` works with Typescript `~2.6.2` only.

Comment: Wow, so quick response! Worked me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Installing angular 9.0.0 solved the problem for me

```
npm install @angular/cli@9.0.0 -g
```

it was breaking for angular 9.1.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm using angular 5 and ionic v3. For me work these changes:

```
"@types/node": "^9.6.55",
"typescript": "3.7.4",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
```

If your are using `@angular/cli` or `@angular-devkit`, in my case I had to remove it in order to build with --prod tag properly.

Be sure also to remove your node_modules and do `npm cache clean -f`, then `npm i` (maybe will be good also remove your package-lock.json)

Comment: Angular 5 ionic 3 here too. This fixed it for me, thanks man. Until the next thing breaks. Can't wait to rewrite this app.