# Angular 7 ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

the ng build gives error but not showing any other clue like file name . This project is asp.net core app with angular 7

```
c:\Users\siva\Myapp\ClientApp>ng build
Date: 2019-08-08T13:22:52.205Z
Hash: 3cf9605e6457ff409625
Time: 6746ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 671 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 93.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 747 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
```

The locally installed packages and its versions are:

```
npm list --depth=0 
+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.9
+-- @angular/animations@7.0.4
+-- @angular/cdk@7.3.7
+-- @angular/cli@7.3.9
+-- @angular/common@7.0.4
+-- @angular/compiler@7.0.4
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@7.0.4
+-- @angular/core@7.0.4
+-- @angular/flex-layout@7.0.0-beta.24
+-- @angular/forms@7.0.4
+-- @angular/http@7.0.4
+-- @angular/language-service@7.0.4
+-- @angular/material@7.3.7
+-- @angular/platform-browser@7.0.4
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.0.4
+-- @angular/router@7.0.4
+-- @types/jasmine@2.8.16
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.6
+-- @types/node@8.10.51
+-- codelyzer@4.5.0
+-- core-js@2.6.9
+-- jasmine-core@2.99.1
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.2.1
+-- karma@4.2.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
+-- karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@2.0.6
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.2
+-- karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
+-- ngx-device-detector@1.3.9
+-- ngx-mask@7.9.10
+-- ngx-mat-select-search@1.8.0
+-- ngx-perfect-scrollbar@7.2.1
+-- ngx-ui-loader@7.2.2
+-- node-sass@4.12.0
+-- protractor@5.4.2
+-- rxjs@6.3.3
+-- ts-node@7.0.1
+-- tslint@5.11.0
+-- typescript@3.1.6
+-- web-animations-js@2.3.2
+-- webpack@4.39.1
`-- zone.js@0.8.29
```

package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build.prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-mask": "^7.9.10",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.8.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.1",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.39.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.51",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.module.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { FakeBackendProvider } from './fake-backend/fake-backend.interceptor';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { MaterialModule } from './shared/modules/material.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    HomeModule,
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    FakeBackendProvider,
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '/'
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried everything that I have found like deleting node_modules folder. npm install, npm cache clear --force and i tried with removing and uninstalling nodejs and source code and started with scratch . Same error coming . How to troubleshoot the cause of error ?

if --aot parameter is used in ng build there is different error is comming

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544854/typeerror-cannot-read-property-flags-of-undefined) can help?

Comment: Have you tred to update all your packages like typescript?Also refer to  this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320181/no-ngmodule-metadata-found-for-appmodule-after-upgrade-from-angular-5-to-angul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not sure, the issue may be due to webpack package installation. Before this error I got error regarding webpack package was not found. I have installed it by `npm install webpack` or `npm install webpack --save`. I didn't remember.  And then another error related to node-saas. So I installed node-sass also. I have read this github issue [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798#issuecomment-350270526). So I have done following steps:

1. deleted the whole asp.net core project
2. uninstalled nodejs
3. deleted folders npm-cache and npm in
   C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\
4. installed nodejs
5. got fresh copy of
   my working project
6. ran `npm install` inside angular project folder where package.json reside
7. ran "node_modules\.bin\ng build"
8. ran "node_modules\.bin\ng serve"

site is running

steps from 1 through 4 is needed for me because I have messed with globally installed package. Those steps may not needed for everyone. deleting node_modules folder may be enough for others instead of these steps

I am working on asp.net core project in VS professional 2017. Starting the project in iis from IDE is enough for me to run the site. So i haven't installed @angular/cli globally.

To put it simply, If I had run command `npm install` inside angular project folder after getting the source code the project, there would be no problem. Since both webpack and node-sass packages are part of ***@angular-devkit/build-angular*** package, we dont need to install it separately. Still I don't know the reason why manual installations of those packages make trouble